# User role from jwt angular/nestjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i'm having issues to retrieve the user's role from the jwt token, it's working for the id but not for the role.

This is my guard

```
      if (this.jwtService.isTokenExpired() || !this.authService.isAuthenticated())  {
         const userRole = this.authService.getUserRole();
              if (route.data.role && route.data.role.indexOf(userRole) === -1) {
            return false;
         }
         // Authorized
         return true;
      }
      this.snackbar.open("You can't go there, please login first.", 'Close', {
         duration: 5000,
         horizontalPosition: 'left',
         verticalPosition: 'bottom',
      });
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
```

AuthService

```
    login(loginForm: LoginForm): Observable<LoginResponseI> {
      return this.http.post<LoginResponseI>('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', loginForm).pipe(
         tap((res: LoginResponseI) => localStorage.setItem(JWT_NAME, JSON.stringify(res))),
         tap(() =>
            this.snackbar.open('Login Successfull', 'Close', {
               duration: 2000,
               horizontalPosition: 'left',
               verticalPosition: 'bottom',
            })
         )
      );
   }
   getUserId(): Observable<any> {
      return of(localStorage.getItem(JWT_NAME)).pipe(
         switchMap((jwt: any) =>
            of(this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(jwt)).pipe(
               map((jwt: any) => JSON.parse(jwt.user_id))
            )
         )
      );
   }
   getUserRole(): Observable<any> {
      return of(localStorage.getItem(JWT_NAME)).pipe(
         switchMap((jwt: any) =>
            of(this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(jwt)).pipe(
               map((jwt: any) => JSON.parse(jwt.user_role))
            )
         )
      );
   }
   isAuthenticated(): boolean {
      const token = localStorage.getItem(JWT_NAME);
      if (token) {
         return true;
      } else return false;
   }

   public getToken(): string | null {
      return window.sessionStorage.getItem(JWT_NAME);
   }

   public getUser(): any {
      const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
      if (user) {
         return JSON.parse(user);
      }

      return {};
   }
```

But i can get datas to fill a form by doing this in a component.ts

```
this.authService
         .getUserId()
         .pipe(
            switchMap((id: number) =>
               this.userService.findOne(id).pipe(
                  tap((user: User) => {
                     this.updateUserForm.patchValue({
                        id: user.id,
                        first_name: user.first_name,
                        last_name: user.last_name,
                        username: user.username,
                        profileImage: user.profileImage,
                     });
                  })
               )
            )
         )
         .subscribe();
```

Here's what I get from the jwt :

```
access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAdGVzdC5mciIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjYyNDcxNzMwLCJleHAiOjE2NjI0NzUzMzB9.CbZkcFU28P7D0btrJzyOQIEEiM63t8iZjPXYMQJBLTg"
expires_in: "3600s"
type: "jwt"
user_id: 1
user_role: "user"
```

Looks like the user's role is undefined in the authGuard.
Any idea of what i'm doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: You are assigning `userRole` in the guard to an Observable. But in the next line you are using it in `route.data.role.indexOf(userRole)` as if it was holding the user_role string.

Answer (score 0):

You can anytime test your JWT token on official [site](https://jwt.io/) and decode it. In your case there is no an `user_role` property, but it has the `role`.

Comment: I'm indeed getting all the datas from the logged in user, and the roles (a string) is set to user so this is what should happen. No clue why i can get it back in the guard

Comment: `getUserRole(): Observable<any> {
      return of(localStorage.getItem(JWT_NAME)).pipe(
         switchMap((jwt: any) =>
            of(this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(jwt)).pipe(
               map((jwt: any) => JSON.parse(jwt.role))
            )
         )
      );
   }`

Comment: change `JSON.parse(jwt.user_role)` to `JSON.parse(jwt.role)`

Comment: I'm getting this error : "undefined" is not valid JSON
it seems to still be undefined